# Is there any code to add particles in header section only?

Tags: reactjs, particles

import React from 'react';
import Particles from 'react-particles-js';

const Header = () =>{

```
const particlesOptions = {
```

particles: {
number: {
value: 30,
density: {
enable: true,
value_area: 800
}
}
}
}

```
return(
    <div className='header' id='particles-js'>
     <Particles />
     
    <h1>Habit Tracker</h1>
    
    </div>
    )
```

}

export default Header

Comment: could you enhance your question, I'm not sure what you want?

Comment: I want to add particles.js in header section only

Comment: Do you mean you want to only import this package and scoped it to Header component?